# webpack export classes from multiple entry files

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm using webpack to bundle up a framework for use by 3rd parties. This framework should expose multiple ES6 classes. Building in a modular fashion, I have written one class per file. What I want to do is build all these files together, and have them bundled up under a given "namespace". Example:

apples.js `export class Apples {...}`
oranges.js `export class Oranges {...}`

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/apples.js', './src/oranges.js'],
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'fruit.js',
    library: 'Fruit',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  }
}
```

However, if I load up this library in the browser and type `Fruit` into the console, I only see the Oranges object under Fruit. Only the last entry file is being exposed back out in the library. Surely enough, the webpack docs confirm this behavior:

> If you pass an array: All modules are loaded upon startup. The last one is exported.
> http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry

My current workaround is to export all my classes from one file, but it's getting pretty unwieldy.

How can I go about setting up a library with multiple entry files that are all exported? Or am I going about something the wrong way here?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to have some index file where you manually define what is exported? I'm not totally following.

Comment: @loganfsmyth that's partly why I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way. I did just try adding an index file where I import Apples and Oranges and then do `export { Apples, Oranges }`. That seems to be a viable solution.

Comment: That's the approach I'd expect. At the end of the day, modules have some public APIs and some private, and the index file is what can define that in a central place.

Comment: @JasonFarnsworth Could you share the code if you solve the problem?

Comment: @ChemicalProgrammer I just ended up with a really simple index.js file that imported and re-exported everything.
`import PiMap from './pi-map'` `import PiWebService from './pi-web-service'`
`export { PiMap, PiWebService }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'd better use a entry.js file to indicate how you organize your serveral modules.

```
import Apples from './apples';
import Oranges from './oranges';

export {
    Apples,
    Oranges
};
```

By the way, if you don't want to write such stupid codes by your own, use Gulp/Grunt to generate the file 'entry.autogenerated.js' by some logic then run webpack with the entry 'entry.autogenerated.js'.

Comment: Can you provide an example with grunt/gulp?