# webpack : multiple entry points

Tags: webpack

I was looking at [this](https://github.com/chandu0101/scalajs-react-template-webpack/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L8) webpack config file and I don't quite understand what happens if more than one entry point is given (as in the example below).

Is it so that the entry points serve as starting points for the dependency search and then the union of the resulting dependencies is what ends up in the bundle ?

```
'use strict';

var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    entry: [
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        publicPath: __dirname  + "/build/",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]


};
```

I looked at the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832116/webpack-multiple-entry-points) but it does not explain what the above config does.

Furthermore,
[here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html) it is written:

> If you pass an array: All modules are loaded upon startup. The last
>   one is exported.

```
entry: ["./entry1", "./entry2"]
```

What is the difference between loading a module and exporting one ?

Answer (score 19):

Exactly!!

As you can see on [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-entry-points) example, with multiple entry points you create 2 or more bundles starting from entry point selected. However you probabliy duplicate (or more) your dependency code in your bundles. Your config, at the moment, perform this task without any kind of optimization.

In the example linked, it uses the common chunk plugin that creates another bundle with common code of entries (to include before the others), useful for multipage webapp.

If you want to add the common chunk plugin, you can simply add this code to your config:

```
plugins: [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        filename: "commons.js",
        name: "commons"
    })
]
```

On [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html) page can find more example (like multiple commons chunk)

Regarding entry argument:

- if you pass a String (`entry: 'entry.js'`), webpack create one bundle starting from it.
- if you pass an array (`entry: ['entry1.js', 'entry2.js']`), it create a bundle starting from entry2, named entry2, and load (and parse) entry1.
- if you pass an object (`entry: {entry1: 'entry1.js', entry2: 'entry2.js'}`), it create two different bundle starting from entries and named as entry key of object.
- if you use a mixed mode like this `entry: {entry1: 'entry1.js', entry2: ['entry2_1.js', 'entry2_2.js'] }`, webpack create a bundle named entry1 starting from entry1.js, and another bundle named entry2 strating from entry2_2.js, but loading firt entry2_1.js.

note that, passing an array of entry, only last is exported, the other js are only loaded.

Comment: Many thanks ! What is the difference between `loading` and `exporting` ? in "note that, passing an array of entry, only last is exported, the other js are only loaded." ?

Comment: Exporting means that those JavaScript composing bundle, when loaded its are only parsed. Is explained (in a similar way) in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511853/webpack-export-classes-from-multiple-entry-files

Comment: @TeoMatthew, you saved my life! Can i use Various plugins for the different entry points in this approach?

Comment: @Dayan like 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'? yes, with something like this: `entry: {entry1: 'entry1.js', entry2: ['plugin1', 'plugin2', 'entry2.js'] }`

Comment: note: CommonsChunkPlugin depreciated. Use this instead: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does handle each entry point seperate. It will include all the dependencies it needs , this means that if both entry points uses jquery. Both will get it into its own bundle. But as said before here,you can however use the commonchunks plugin. it will at certain point (as you can decide the number needed) move the multiple used modules to a certain common module